# iOS - Application crashes when using optimization

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

When i build my app with any optimization level other than -o0, the application crashes at some point because of EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I tries all possible optimization levels (-o1/2/3/s) and all crashes the application.

The compiler is LLVM 3.0.

Any idea why it happens? Is this some known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check for uninitialized variables as a possible cause.  The different settings causes things to move around and something that is "safe" in the unoptimized build could hold a stale pointer in another.

Comment: I also thought at this direction, but it is hard to find such variable in a large app. Is there any automatic tool that can do the search for me?

Comment: You could try -Wall and then resolving all warnings.  If optimization is turned on then the warning error -Wuninitialized
"Warn if an automatic variable is used without first being initialized or if a variable may be clobbered by a setjmp call..." see this list for more details about that.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html